# аргумент типа "wchar_t *" несовместим с параметром типа "char *

Tags: c++

```
#define  _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#pragma execution_character_set("utf-8")
#include<TCHAR.H>
#include <format>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(lib,"Advapi32")

using namespace std;

const char* disk_type[] =
{
    "unknown", "no root dir", "removable", "fixed", "remote", "CD-ROM", "RAMDISK"
};

int main()
{

    {
        cout << "Drives:\n";
        DWORD d = GetLogicalDrives();
        for (wchar_t  disk = 'A'; d; d >>= 1, disk++)
        {
            if (d & 1)
            {
                wchar_t root[80] = { 0 };
                root[0] = disk;
                strcat(root, ":\\");
                cout << "Drive " << disk << ": " << disk_type[GetDriveType(root)] << "\n";
                DWORD SectorsPerCluster, BytesPerSector, NumberOfFreeClusters, TotalNumberOfClusters;
                if (GetDiskFreeSpace( root, &SectorsPerCluster, &BytesPerSector,
                    &NumberOfFreeClusters, &TotalNumberOfClusters))
                {
                    unsigned long long t = SectorsPerCluster, f;
                    t *= BytesPerSector; f = t;
                    t = t * TotalNumberOfClusters / 1024 / 1024;
                    f = f * NumberOfFreeClusters / 1024 / 1024;
                    //cout << format("Free space: {0:10lld} of {1:10lld MB}\n", f, t);
                    cout << format("Free space: {0:10d} of {1:10d} MB\n", f, t);

                    wchar_t  volName[256], fileSystem[256];
                    if (GetVolumeInformation(root, volName, 256, 0, 0, 0, fileSystem, 256))
                    {
                        cout
                            << "File system: " << fileSystem << ", volume name: "
                            << volName << "\n";
                    }
                }
                cout << "\n";
            }
        }
        cout << "----------------8<----------------\n";
    }
    {
        unsigned long long M;
        wchar_t  Name[256], user[256];
        DWORD sz = 256, uz = 256;
        if (GetUserName(user, &uz) &&
            GetComputerName(Name, &sz) &&
            GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory(&M))
        {
            cout << "Computer \"" << Name << "\" (user name \"" << user
                << "\") has " << M / 1024 << " MB of physical memory\n";
            cout << "----------------8<----------------\n";
        }
    }
    {
        wchar_t  path[300];
        if (GetSystemDirectory(path, 300))
            cout << "System directory : " << path << "\n";
        if (GetWindowsDirectory(path, 300))
            cout << "Windows directory: " << path << "\n";
        if (GetCurrentDirectory(300, path))
            cout << "Current directory: " << path << "\n";
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну я писал этот код не для Unicode, только и всего... Перепишите с использованием `wchar_t` и `wcout`, если Unicode критичен.

Comment: @Harry я уже и Unicode попробувал, и ваш пример, изменял Character Set. Ошибка как была так и есть

Answer (score 3):

`wchar_t` действительно не совместим с обычным `char`, ведь он предназначен для 2-байтовых кодировок *(и следовательно занимает 2 байта в памяти)*, в отличии от однобайтового `char`.

Всё что вам нужно, как правильно указали в комментариях использовать функции для `wchar_t`.

1. `cout` - `wcout`
2. `strcat` - `wcscat`